# Nginx reverse proxy fails to tunnel file requests

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm running an application inside Tomcat on port `2211` and all is well. However I would like to serve this application whenever anyone browses to `site.com/service` and for that I came up with this Nginx proxy pass setup.

```
  location /service {
    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Frame-Options     SAMEORIGIN;

    proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:2211;
  }
```

But when I browse to `site.com/service` I can only see my jetty application in plain HTML. For some reason all files even though they exist on Tomcat the browser receives a 404 reply for all of them.

I've looked into how the browser is requesting the file, for example:

```
<img src="/themes/logo.png">
```

This image instead of being requested at `site.com/service/themes/logo.png` is being asked at `site.com/themes/logo.png`, which obviously doesn't work and therefore 404 not found. The same happens to all other files, it should be looking for them at `site.com/service` not on the root folder `site.com`.

Surely Nginx is missing some configuration parameters, could you point towards it?

Answer (score 0):

Both nginx and the image are behaving correctly, the proxy is returning the html just as it is, the problem is that the tomcat server thinks that it's the root, so it returns all the assets relative to the root, you can fix this in a couple of ways

1. Either change the subfolder `/service` to a subdomain `service.domain.com` this way the assets will truely be in the root.
2. Somehow configure the tomcat server to return all it's links relative to the `/service` folder, an easy way would be adding a base inside the `head` tag

   ```
   <base href='http://domain.com/service'>
   ```

   This way the urls will all be absolute, but that will only make the urls functional under that proxy
3. Instead of modifying your tomcat application, you can tell nginx to add that header by it self, by doing some replacement in the returned html using [sub_filter](http://nginx.org/r/sub_filter), it would insert in inside the `head` tag

   ```
   sub_filter '</head>' '<base href='$scheme://$server_name/service></head>';
   ```

Comment: Thank you. 
Unfortunately I cannot use options one and two, so I went for the third one. I added `sub_filter` and after viewing the source I can see that the `<base>` tag was added correctly pointing towards `site.com/service` however the browser isn't considering it and is still looking up for the file on the root folder was it did before. Any thoughts why?

Comment: The images aren't using full path are they ? all images are relative correct?

Comment: No their not. Their all relative. Exactly like this `<img src="/themes/logo.png">`

Comment: ok my bad, the url starts with a `/` so that ignores that subfolder and routes back to the root, not sure if there's another clean way to do it or not, another way would be using the same sub_filter to overwrite all the assets paths, like `sub_filter '"/themes/"' '"/service/themes/"'`, this would work but it would be a load on nginx plus it might match another thing that's not intended to be replaced, or miss things that we want to replace.

Comment: Using `sub_filter` I will match all `src="/` and `href="/` and append `service` before the slash. However I don't think I can have multiple `sub_filter` conditions inside a single `location`, because when I have only one its works, with more than one nginx says I have a error on such condition. Any thoughts on how I can have more than on `sub_filter` ?

Comment: not sure if this helps but try adding this `sub_filter_once off;`

Comment: No it didn't. I will try to find some other parameter which will do the trick.